# How do we prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x$ converges according to the comparison test?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that:
> $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^2+1} dx$$
> converges by choosing a suitable comparison test.

I can divide the interval into two parts, the one with negative values and another with positive.

According to the theorem I can calculate whether the integral is convergent or divergent with positive values but I don’t know how to do this with negative part

Comment: It converges if the two halves of the integral converge, and as you have an even function $f(x)=-f(x)$, if one half converges then the other does too

Comment: @Henry I suspect that you intended to say $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes I did - thank you

Comment: You never actually state what the problem is, Sofia. If the problem is to determine whether the integral converges, then this information should be edited into the body of your question.

Comment: For a less rigorous intuitive way you can observe that a rational integrand where the denominator has a higher power can only diverge harmonically. In this case, 6-2=4, which is definitely not harmonic, thus the integral converges

Answer (score 5):

If you are just asked to show this integral converges, all that is needed is an upper bound. For that, as other people have already pointed out, since $f(x)= x^2/(x^6+x^2+1)$ is even, it suffices to check  $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges. You say in the title of your question that you are supposed to use the comparison test to check convergence. In order to do that, you want to bound $f(x)$ by some simpler function, where by "simpler" I mean one that you know how to integrate explicitly (preferably with as little calculation as possible, as we just want a bound and are not asked for one of some particular magnitude).

The cheapest thing to do is probably to note that for $x>0$ we have

$$ 0< \frac{x^2}{x^6+x^2+1} <\frac{1}{x^4},$$

and since $x^{-4}$ decays quickly as $x \to \infty$, the integral must converge, e.g., if $R>1$ then

$$
\begin{split}
\int_{0}^{R} f(x)dx  &= \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx + \int_{1}^R f(x)dx\\
&< \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx+ \int_{0}^\infty x^{-4} dx \\
&= \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx + [-\frac{x^{-3}}{3}]_1^R = \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx+ \frac{1-R^{-3}}{3} \\
&< \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx + \frac{1}{3} = C
\end{split}
$$

hence the integrals $\int_{0}^R f(x)dx$ are all bounded above by $C$, and so they converge as $R\to \infty$.

If you don't like leaving the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ as a constant which you haven't explicitly estimated, then the crudest thing to do would be to note that $f(x)<1$ for all $x>0$ so $\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx <\int_0^1 1dx=1$. If you wanted to estimate that integral slightly less crudely, then even the simple estimate $0<f(x)<x^2$ (which holds for all $x>0$) gives $\int_{0}^1f(x)dx <1/3$ and hence that $C<2/3$.

Comment: Great answer! I was also thinking of using that $\frac 1{x^4}$ but I realized that it has a singularity at $x=0$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**

Since the argument of the proposed integral is even, the convergence problem can be reduced to the study of convergence of the expression on the RHS:
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + x^{2} + 1}\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Then I would recommend you to notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + x^{2} + 1} & \leq \frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + 1} = \frac{1}{x^{4} - x^{2} + 1} = \frac{1}{(x^{2} + 1)^{2} - 3x^{2}} = \frac{1}{(x^{2} - \sqrt{3}x + 1)(x^{2} + \sqrt{3}x + 1)}
\end{align*}
where you can apply the partial fraction method.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: +1 I like your hint! This answer shows that bounding integrals is as simple as removing some terms in the denominator >D

Comment: Yes, thanks! It worked and it’s much more understandable

Comment: @SofiaIbragimova you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Divide this integral into two parts. We have that  $$\frac{x^2}{x^6+x^2+1}<\frac1{x^2+1}$$ and $$\frac{1}{x^6+x^2+1}<\frac1{x^2+1}$$So we have that $$I<2\pi$$Which is a very dirty upper bound but it does the deal. And by the way: $$0<\frac{x^2}{x^6+x^2+1}$$So $I>0$

Comment: How do you prove that when you separate the integral one part converges to $\pi$? Contour integration?

Comment: @JacquesTarr I noticed I left a lot of things out of my answer. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @JacquesTarr I changed my answer now, thank you very much for your kind comment! I would do it by contour integration if I were to evaluate it though ;)

Comment: That clears things up! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

By @Átila Correia’s good upper bound function
$$
\frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^2+1}\le\frac{x^2+1}{x^6+1}=\frac{1}{x^4-x^2+1},
$$
it suffices to prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4-x^2+1} d x$ is convergent.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \because\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4-x^2+1} d x \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^2}+1} \cdot \frac{d x}{x^2}=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4-x^2+1} d x \\
& \therefore 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4-x^2+1} d x =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1+x^2}{x^4-x^2+1} d x=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}+1}{x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-1} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+1}=\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]_0^{\infty}=\pi \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence $
\displaystyle  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^2+1} d x=2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x^6+x^2+1} d x
$ is convergent.

Comment: Great answer! I didn't see that $x^6+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$. Your upper bound is better than mine as you didn't remove much terms from the denominator like I did :)

Answer (score 2):

*Just if you wish to go beyond.*

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + x^{2} + 1}\,dx & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + x^{2} + 1}\,dx
\end{align*}

Write
$$\frac{x^{2} + 1}{x^{6} + x^{2} + 1}=\frac{x^{2} + 1}{(x^2-a)(x^2-b)(x^2-c)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition, the integrand write
$$\frac{a+1}{(a-b) (a-c) \left(x^2-a\right)}+\frac{b+1}{(b-c) (b-c)
   \left(x^2-b\right)}+\frac{c+1}{(c-a) (c-b) \left(x^2-c\right)}$$
to face three simple integrals
$$I_k=\int_0^\infty \frac {dx}{x^2-k}=\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{-k}}$$

Solving the cubic in $x^2$ shows a real root
$$a=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\,\sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)$$
and the other roots are easily obtained solving the remaining quadratic equation in $x^2$.

Converting the monster to decimals, the integral is $$0.7996631487800142755\cdots \pi$$